# Why is there anomalous trend in third ionization energy for Pr-Pm and Dy-Er?

Tags: periodic-trends, ionization-energy, rare-earth-elements

It is not hard to observe the anomalously flat regions at Pr-Pm and Dy-Er in the trend of IE3 of lanthanides:[image], each described as the "first quarter" and "third quarter". Why is this the case? I used to convince myself this has something to do with the orbital and total angular momentum of the ground term symbols of the Ln(2+) and Ln(3+) ions.

Comment: Dear OP, I would advise you to take a look at the electronic configurations and see if you get any clues.